# Vuforia: Render model at specific position of image target

Tags: image, position, webcam, target, vuforia

I want to know how the image target position works because I want to render a model on a specific position or point of image target. How can i solve this problem using laptop external camera?

When I move my image target from one position to another, I've noticed that there isn't a significant difference in the x, y, and z values of its position. Due to this, I'm facing challenges in accurately rendering the 3D model at a specific position on the image target.

Answer (score 0):

When tracking an target for AR one can assume that either the target is stationary and the camera is moving, or that the camera is stationary and the object is moving, or that both are moving in a third stationary coordinate system.

When using an USB camera Vuforia assumes that the object is stationary and that the camera is moving. Thus if you want to render a 3D model at a fixed position with respect to the Image Target the only thing you have to do is to define its position in the Image Target coordinate system and keep this position unchanged. This should be enough.

Here you can find some extra information on Vuforia coordinate systems https://library.vuforia.com/device-tracking/spatial-frame-reference